# Two related models, access data via request.user

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm a bit stumped. So I have two models, as shown in models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    key_expires = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.date.today())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural='User profiles'


class ImageDoc(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    imgfile = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

It's a simple profile function, and what I'm trying to do is display images related only to the user after they log in.

Here's my views.py file:

```
def sign_in(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/', context)
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Verify your account!")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")


def populateContext(request, context):
    context['authenticated'] = request.user.is_authenticated()
    if context['authenticated'] == True:
        context['username'] = request.user.username


def index(request):
    context = {}
    populateContext(request, context)

    context.update(image_gallery = ImageDoc.objects.only('imgfile'))
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

In the index.html page, I can display the user who has logged in, thanks to populateContext above. This includes these:

```
{{ request.user.first_name }} {{ request.user.last_name }} {{ request.user.username }} {{ request.user.email }} {{ request.user.id }}
```

However, I don't know how to display "imgfile" from the related model. It works if I do this:

```
{% for x in image_gallery %}
    <img src="{{ x.imgfile }}"> 
{% endfor %}
```

But only because I updated the context above to include it in. Ideally I want the image to display just on a particular user's page. Exactly like a member gallery. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple method for `UserProfile` model, that will return all `images` related to current `user`:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # some stuff here

    def get_images(self):
        return ImageDoc.objects.filter(user=self)
```

Now you can access `images` in a template:

```
{% for image in user.userprofile.get_images %}
    <img src="{{ image.imgfile }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Fantastic! It works like a charm. Is this the only way to do it?

Comment: There's no need to define `get_images` at all. Django already provides the reverse accessor, `imagedoc_set`, so you can do `{% for image in  user.userprofile.imagedoc_set.all %}`.

Comment: That works as well, thanks @Daniel-Roseman.

I have another question. Is it possible for members to upload files that link only to their account, using the context? So the upload link to do this remains as "www.whatever.com/upload/"?

Comment: Yes, you can by rewriting the `save` method for uploading `form` and setting current `user` as an image owner.

Comment: Thanks @chem1st! I'll work hard on this. Appreciate it guys!

Comment: Is there a good starting point which I can learn or follow to accomplish this?